# How do I use a str replace regex for deep replacement?

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace a part of an URL with a string.

lets assume this is the URL `https://playground.com/community/mefan/?page_id=2069` or `https://playground.com/community/mefan/activity-3`

All I wish to do is, replace the last part with `activity`, and get the URL like this : `https://playground.com/community/mefan/activity`

And if in the URL there is already `activity` exists then there will be no change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you are looking for is:

```
$re = '/(https:\/\/playground\.com\/community\/mefan\/).*/';
$str = 'https://playground.com/community/mefan/?page_id=2069';
$subst = '$1activity';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Please look at [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/TMOHP5/1) for proof.

Comment: Really good approach, But i can't understand the pattern here. You just took the words those are in the sting. But is there any general words for it??

Comment: But i can't understand the pattern here. You just took the words those are in the sting. But is there any general words for it??

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you might have been familiar with Regex101.com where the complete explanation is shown on the right hand side `explanation` panel when you click the link.

Comment: Basically, we are looking for the string `https://playground.com/community/mefan/`, followed by anything (`.*`). The `$1` part will take that searched for string and discard anything that follows and replace it with `activity`

Comment: Off setting anonymous downvote (possibly from no regex def in answer but should have left a comment about it if that was the case). Could change delimiter to avoid escaping, and use a reset to avoid capture group. Possible update, https://3v4l.org/p7idp